# When attempting to connect MetaMask wallet to React - if user clicks out of the MetaMask modal, the modal doesn't reappear

Tags: reactjs, browser, blockchain, metamask

My app connects MetaMask to react on button click.

On button click, the app looks to see if MetaMask is installed and displays the MetaMask login modal if so.

If the users navigates away from the MetaMask modal without logging in and clicks "connect wallet" again the MetaMask modal does not reappear.

[Video of Issue]
https://www.loom.com/share/a459da718aae4c69912535d56d82b0dd

**Code**

Here is the code at the top of the component.

```
const WalletCard = () => {
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);
const [defaultAccount, setDefaultAccount] = useState(null);
const [userBalance, setUserBalance] = useState(null);
const [networkName, setNetworkName] = useState("");

const connectWalletHandler = () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.ethereum
        .request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
        .then((result) => {
          accountChangedHandler(result[0]);
        });
    } else {
      setErrorMessage("Install MetaMask");
      alert(errorMessage);
    }
    window.ethereum.request({ method: "net_version" }).then((chainID) => {
      chainID === "1"
        ? setNetworkName("Ethereum Main Network")
        : chainID === "3"
        ? setNetworkName("Ropsten Test Network")
        : chainID === "4"
        ? setNetworkName("Rinkeby Test Network")
        : chainID === "5"
        ? setNetworkName("Goerli Test Network")
        : chainID === "42"
        ? setNetworkName("Kovan Test Network")
        : setNetworkName("Network not found");
    });
  };

  //  Account Change from Connected Wallet
  const accountChangedHandler = (newAccount) => {
    setDefaultAccount(newAccount);
    getAccountBalance(newAccount.toString());
  };

  // Get Account Balance
  const getAccountBalance = (account) => {
    window.ethereum
      .request({ method: "eth_getBalance", params: [account, "latest"] })
      .then((balance) => {
        setUserBalance(ethers.utils.formatEther(balance));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setErrorMessage(error.message);
      });
  };

  const disconnectWallet = () => {
    window.location.reload();
  };

  const chainChangedHandler = () => {
    window.location.reload();
  };

  //  Listen for account change and disconnect
  window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", chainChangedHandler);

  // Listen for chain change and disconnect
  window.ethereum.on("chainChanged", chainChangedHandler);
```

**Returns**

Code inside the return statement

```
return (
    <div className="master-container">
      <div className="card-container">
        <div className="image-container">
          <img
            className="img"
            src={
              networkName === "Ethereum Main Network" && defaultAccount
                ? ethLogo
                : networkName === "Ropsten Test Network" && defaultAccount
                ? rIcon
                : networkName === "Rinkeby Test Network" && defaultAccount
                ? rink
                : networkName === "Goerli Test Network" && defaultAccount
                ? goerli
                : networkName === "Kovan Test Network" && defaultAccount
                ? kovan
                : mmLogo
            }
            height={100}
            width={100}
          ></img>
        </div><div className="card-text-container">
          <h1 className="card-title">
            {" "}
            {defaultAccount ? `${networkName}` : "MetaMask Wallet Connector"}
          </h1>

          <h2 className="card-text-balance">
            {userBalance ? `Balance: ${userBalance} ETH` : ""}
          </h2>

          <h4 className="card-text-address">
            {defaultAccount ? `Address: ${defaultAccount}` : ""}
          </h4>

          <p className="card-subtext">
            {defaultAccount
              ? `You are connected to the ${networkName}`
              : "Connect to view account details"}{" "}
          </p>

          <div className="btn-container">
            {defaultAccount ? (
              ""
            ) : (
              <button className="btn-connect" onClick={connectWalletHandler}>
                Connect Wallet
              </button>
            )}

            {defaultAccount ? (
              <button className="btn-disconnect" onClick={disconnectWallet}>
                Disconnect Wallet
              </button>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>);
    };
    export default WalletCard;
```

**Thoughts**

*connectWallerHandler* gets called on the initial button click. When the button is clicked a second time the console indicates "eth_requestAccounts" method has already been made.

This makes sense ^

but I am struggling with the best way to indicate to the user that they need to open
the MetaMask browser extension and login since the modal doesn't appear. I think the solution is somewhere in the area below:

**Connect Wallet Handler**

```
 const connectWalletHandler = () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.ethereum
        .request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
        .then((result) => {
          accountChangedHandler(result[0]);
        });
    } else {
      setErrorMessage("Install MetaMask");
      alert(errorMessage);
    }
    window.ethereum.request({ method: "net_version" }).then((chainID) => {
      chainID === "1"
        ? setNetworkName("Ethereum Main Network")
        : chainID === "3"
        ? setNetworkName("Ropsten Test Network")
        : chainID === "4"
        ? setNetworkName("Rinkeby Test Network")
        : chainID === "5"
        ? setNetworkName("Goerli Test Network")
        : chainID === "42"
        ? setNetworkName("Kovan Test Network")
        : setNetworkName("Network not found");
    });
  };
```

**Card Content**

```
  <div className="card-text-container">
          <h1 className="card-title">
            {" "}
            {defaultAccount ? `${networkName}` : "MetaMask Wallet Connector"}
          </h1>

          <h2 className="card-text-balance">
            {userBalance ? `Balance: ${userBalance} ETH` : ""}
          </h2>

          <h4 className="card-text-address">
            {defaultAccount ? `Address: ${defaultAccount}` : ""}
          </h4>

          <p className="card-subtext">
            {defaultAccount
              ? `You are connected to the ${networkName}`
              : "Connect to view account details"}{" "}
          </p>

          <div className="btn-container">
            {defaultAccount ? (
              ""
            ) : (
              <button className="btn-connect" onClick={connectWalletHandler}>
                Connect Wallet
              </button>
            )}

            {defaultAccount ? (
              <button className="btn-disconnect" onClick={disconnectWallet}>
                Disconnect Wallet
              </button>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you visit extensions tab, you see this:

[image]

If you check the console, you might have this error

[image]

Because metamask does not allow to make 2nd request in a row. you have to go to extensions and login metamask